# Issue with non-breaking space

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am facing issue when i changed font-family of my site from `Gotham Pro` to `Gotham` and every number that was formatted via my currency formatter function is breaking styles. When `&nbsp` character is removed everything seems to be fine. My function for currency

```
const format = (n) => new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(n);
```

I tried to change this function to do its thing in different way, but problem is not going away

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking styles?" Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67497105/edit) to show a specific example of the problem. Also show what you mean by "when &nbsp character is removed everything seems to be fine."

Answer (score 2):

Did you put semicolon after &nbsp? `&nbsp;`

Comment: I did not put anything manually, everything was done by foramtter function, which did put semicolon

Comment: Please try  to add semicolon and edit manually for checking if the style is breaking or not